# Idiomatic Scala Map upsert

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm working with a map in Scala and doing the usual "if there's no value associated with a key, create it, put it in the map and return it":

```
def alphaMemory(key : AlphaMemoryKey) = {
    var am = map.getOrElse(key, null)
    if(am == null) {
        am = new AlphaMemory(key)
        map.put(key, am)
    }
    am
}
```

To me, this does not feel like idiomatic Scala code. It feels like Java. Is there a more succinct way of writing this? It looked like maybe I could override Map.default() to insert the new value and return it. Not sure though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[`mutable.Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html) has [`getOrElseUpdate`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#getOrElseUpdate(key:K,op:=>V):V) which does exactly what you want, no idiom necessary.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't realize that the default parameter was "by-name" so I had convinced myself it would be evaluated each time it was called. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing how this would be done with immutable maps?

Comment: @Marcus Downing Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4385976/460387) for solutions for `immutable.Map`