# idiomatic "get or else update" for immutable.Map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the idiomatic way of a getOrElseUpdate for immutable.Map instances?. I use the snippet below, but it seems verbose and inefficient

```
var map = Map[Key, Value]()

def foo(key: Key) = {
  val value = map.getOrElse(key, new Value)
  map += key -> value
  value
}
```

Comment: `map += key -> value` --> Perhaps you mean `mutable.Map` map?

Comment: I think you mean mutable.Map!? You are using += in your code which does not work for immutable.Map.
For mutable.Map there is getOrElseUpdate().

Comment: @Vasil Remeniuk, @michid: Sure it works. When there's no '+=' method the compiler converts the expression to 'map = map + key -> value'. I updated the question to make it clear map is a var

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me summarise your problem:

- You want to call a method on a immutable data structure
- You want it to return some value *and* reassign a `var`
- Because the data structure is immutable, you’ll need to

  - return a new immutable data structure, or
  - do the assignment inside the method, using a supplied closure

So, either your signature has to look like

```
def getOrElseUpdate(key: K): Tuple2[V, Map[K,V]]
//... use it like
val (v, m2) = getOrElseUpdate(k)
map = m2
```

or

```
def getOrElseUpdate(key: K, setter: (Map[K,V]) => Unit): V
//... use it like
val v = getOrElseUpdate(k, map = _)
```

If you can live with one of these solutions, you could add your own version with an implicit conversion but judging by the signatures alone, i wouldn’t think any of these is in the standard library.

Comment: I guess from all the answers it means there's no idiomatic way (other than @Daniel's suggestion of working with immutable objects all the way)

Comment: The problem is that you want to reassign your variable while doing something else. There is no way to do that from inside another method without help (e.g. it gets ugly). You’d need proper support for pass-by-reference for that (which is only possible with some hacks in Scala).

Comment: It's actually pretty easy to get pass-by-reference semantics in Scala: `case class Var[T](var ref: T) { def apply() = ref; def update(v: T) = ref = v }`.  Idiomatic? No.

Comment: @Aaron Novstrup: But this requires the user to actively apply some wrapper (and unwrap it afterwards), hence it cannot be done without help inside some method. In most cases, supplying a setter closure (`m = _`) will be the better solution for the stuff you’d need pass-by-reference for.

Comment: Wrapping/unwrapping is fairly transparent: e.g. `val v = new Var(1); v() = 2; println(v())`, but I agree that a closure is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 16):

I would probably implement a `getOrElseUpdated` method like this:

```
def getOrElseUpdated[K, V](m: Map[K, V], key: K, op: => V): (Map[K, V], V) =
  m.get(key) match {
    case Some(value) => (m, value)
    case None => val newval = op; (m.updated(key, newval), newval)
  }
```

which either returns the original map if `m` has a mapping for `key` or another map with the mapping `key -> op` added. The definition of this method is similar to `getOrElseUpdate` of `mutable.Map`.

Comment: you are the only one who actually answered the question :-)

Answer (score 8):

There's no such way - map mutation (update), when you're getting a map value, is a side effect (which contradicts to immutability/functional style of programming).

When you want to make a new immutable map with the default value, if another value for the specified key doesn't exist, you can do the following:

```
map + (key -> map.getOrElse(key, new Value))
```

Comment: Your code is lines 1-2 in my 'foo', but it returns a map, not the value

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `withDefault` or `withDefaultValue` if you have an immutable map?

Comment: withDefault and withDefaultValue will return a default value, but will not update the map.

Comment: @IttayD And what difference does that make?

Comment: @Daniel `withDefault` and `withDefaultValue` will not give the same semantics as @IttayD's code above with respect to object identity. `withDefault` would create new, potentially unequal values on multiple retrievals of a given key. `withDefaultValue` would return a particular value on retrievals of different keys.

Comment: @Aaron True, which may or may not be of relevance. That's my point here: is there any particular reason why it cannot work? One should not discard it just because it was not the solution one has first envisioned.

Comment: @Daniel, the difference is that if Value is mutable, I want the same reference that was returned to be returned the next call. Even if Value is immutable, I don't want to create it each call.

Comment: @IttayD Values are not created anew by withDefaultValue, and withDefault can easily use a memoizing function.

Comment: @Daniel so in withDefault I'd need to use a map, bringing me back to square one

Comment: @IttayD But in that map you could just use `withDefault` with a memoizing function! ;-)